# Jenkins Setup for Selenium Grid to run automation on devices

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, appium

I have been trying to create a hub and register nodes using selenium grid on Jenkins CI.

I have tried creating "execute shell" and perform this process first running the selenium hub and tried registering the nodes in further steps but nothing worked. If I do it in this way. It only runs Selenium Hub but unable to register the nodes to it.

I have tried installing the selenium grid plugin for jenkins but nothing works.

Finally, I tried creating three different jobs to start and hub and register nodes to it.

Is there anyway I can do this process in a single job or Is there anyway if I run the first job which is starting the hub and then automatically the other two jobs should start the process.

Comment: you can certainly pipeline the jenkins jobs I believe

Answer (score 1):

Starting hub and registering node on Jenkins server is one-time process which you can do from terminal.

Or

In Jenkins execute shell section try below commands:

- To start grid hub

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -timeout 300000 &

// do not forget to add "&" at the end to run this process in the background.

- To register node

  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register &

Comment: Thank u it worked. Is there anyway to stop the build after completion of all the tests.

Comment: Jenkins build will finish automatically after completion of all the tests.
If you want to kill the Grid hub and node process you can kill these process using the port number.
for example in post build script you can call
`fuser -k -n tcp 4444  // to kill grid hub`

`fuser -k -n tcp 5555  // to kill grid node`

Comment: Where is the execute shell section in Jenkins?

Comment: In Build section see drop down to select execute shell option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run a Selenium Grid from Jenkins UNLESS the grid is ran in the foreground of a user session so that there is a "space" to run the browsers within.   It probably wont work if you run the grid as a background process.   You didn't say if your using Linux or Windows, but in either case, you'll have the same problem I think.

Comment: I am using OS X. I have gone through various documents but nothing helped me.

Comment: By default, the Selenium Grid Hub contains a node registered to it.  You don't really have to run your Nodes as a separate Java process.  Literally, follow the documentation, start the Grid with default options, and you can navigate to the Grid admin url to verify.  Easy.